# Android: Fragments in FragmentPagerAdapter do not display data in landscape after device turned on

Tags: android, android-fragments, orientation

I had created tabview with swipe using `Fragments` and `FragmentPagerAdapter`. In the fragment's hosting activity, I had added a fragment and that fragment shows `tabview` using `TabHost`. 1st tab has a `listview` that displays data from DB using `CursorLoader` and the 2nd one is `mapView`.

Everything works fine in portrait mode.

Problem occurs in following case:

1. User is using app in landscape mode. He opened tabbed view screen. Data is displayed in the listview from the cursor loader. Mapview is also displayed in the second tab. So far everything is working as required.
2. He left the app as is.(Means, he did not pressed back button, home button or switched to another app)
3. Screen went off after some time.
4. When user unlocks the device, my app's tabbed view will be visible again. But,now listview does not show any data and mapview also disappeared.

**ClientListFragment**

```
public class ClientListFragment extends SwipeRefreshListFragment {
    private static final String TAG = "ClientListFragment";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        setColorScheme(R.color.gplus_color_1, R.color.gplus_color_2,
            R.color.gplus_color_3, R.color.gplus_color_4);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        Log.e(TAG, "onResume");
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        Log.e(TAG, "onActivityCreated");
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        // Log.i(TAG, "onPause");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        Log.e(TAG, "onStop");
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        Log.e(TAG, "onDestroy");
    }
}
```

**Map Fragment**

```
public class ClientMapFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "ClientMapFragment";

    private GoogleMap googleMap;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
}
```

**Activity**

```
public class ClientActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        boolean isTablet = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.isTablet);
        if (isTablet)
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
        else
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_PORTRAIT);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_clients);

        ClientFragment clientFragment = new ClientFragment();
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putBoolean("ShouldChangeActionBarTitle", true);
        clientFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        getFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, clientFragment,
                        getResources().getString(R.string.clients_fragment))
                .commit();
    }
}
```

**FragmentpagerAdapter**

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {


private static final String TAG = "TabsPagerAdapter";

    private ArrayList<Fragment> mFragments = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
    FragmentManager fm;

    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        this.fm = fm;
        mFragments.add(new ClientListFragment());
        mFragments.add(new ClientMapFragment());
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {
        Log.e(TAG, "getItem");
        return mFragments.get(index);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragments.size();
    }
}
```

**Update 1**

So, after doing hours of research I came to a conclusion that, it is problem with fragment's state in the `FragmentPagerAdapter`. When screen is turned off fragmentpager's `saveState` is  called.. When the device is unlocked again, fragment's will be restored from previous state. I verified that `LoaderManager callbacks` are called, and data was also fetched from DB. But, didn't appeared on screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't even bothered about looking at my activities code at once. Everytime, a new fragment was created in onCreate(). The fix is very simple.

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    Log.e(TAG, "onCreate savedInstanceState == null");
    ClientFragment clientFragment = new ClientFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putBoolean("ShouldChangeActionBarTitle",
            shouldChangeActionBarTitle);
    clientFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .add(R.id.fragmentContainer, clientFragment,
                    getResources().getString(R.string.clients_fragment))
            .commit();
}
```